# Сортировка массива usort

Tags: массивы, php, сортировка

В предыдущем вопросе о сортировке массива по расстояниям [@VladD](/users/10105/vladd) подсказал ответ:

1) Заводите структуру, в которой будут храниться данные. Например, класс или массив.

2) В цикле делаете вот что:

```
$alldata = array();
while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
{
    // $alldata[] = <тут создаём структуру (например, подмассив) и пакуем в неё данные из $row>
    // например:
    $datum = array();
    $datum['title'] = stripslashes(check_html($row['title'], "nohtml"));
    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $lon = $row['lon'];
    $datum['lat'] = $lat;
    $datum['lon'] = $lon;
    $datum['distance'] = distance($lat, $lon, $latlon);
    // и остальные данные тоже пакуем
    $alldata[] = $datum;
}
```

3) Сортируем (usort)

4) Выводим:

```
foreach ($alldata as $datum)
{
    // достаёте данные из структуры
    $title = $datum['title'];
    $lat = $datum['lat'];
    $lon = $datum['lon'];
    echo '<div class="placePages"> ...
}
```

Я что-то с пунктом 3) не могу разобраться. Мне нужно сделать сортировку `usort` по рассчитанной дистанции `$datum['distance']` в порядке убывания. Как это сделать с пом. `usort`?

Что-то вроде `usort($alldata, $datum['distance']);` ?

Понимаю, что вопрос глупый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [документации](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php):

```
function comparedistance($a, $b)
{
    $d1 = $a['distance'];
    $d2 = $b['distance'];
    if ($d1 > $d2)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    elseif($d1 > $d2)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

usort($alldata, "comparedistance");
```

Comment: @VladD, простите за навязчивость)) получилось, спасибо.

Comment: @MyNameIs: пожалуйста!

Comment: Тело функции можно записать чуть короче: return $a["distance"]-$a["distance"];

Comment: и вообще: usort($alldata, function($a,$b){return...});

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Я не уверен насчёт PHP, но в C и C++ в случае, например, `$a["distance"] == MAXINT` и `$b["distance"] == -1`, разность даст `MAXINT + 1`, то есть, отрицательное число из-за переполнения. А как PHP справляется с этим?

Comment: Без проблем. PHP и не цепляется за формат. Вплоть до того, что в случае переполнения формата int тупо переходит на float. Зато с учётом этого замечания я начал догадываться, почему в доках по PHP такой кошмар творится.

Comment: Описанную ситуацию на СО я обходил в теме про решето Эратосфена, когда вблизи MAXINT применил цикл по убыванию. Но там мне float мешал. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/24957/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0