# Как с qsort отсортировать массив так, чтобы нечетные числа остались на своем месте?

Tags: c, qsort

Привет! Не получается решить задачу (ниже есть моя попытка решения):

---

Напечатайте входную последовательность натуральных чисел, отсортировав ее по **возрастанию четных чисел, нечетные остаются на своих местах** с помощью страндартной функции языка с **qsort**.

**Входные данные**

Целое число 0 < N ≤ 1000. Затем N натуральных чисел, не превышающих 30000, через пробел.

**Выходные данные**

Нечетные числа остаются на своих местах, четные отсортированы по возрастанию.

---

Написал такую функцию сравнения:

```
int cmp_int(const void * p1, const void * p2) {
    int s1 = *(int*)p1; int s2 = *(int*)p2;
    if ((s1 % 2 == 0) && (s2 % 2 == 0)) {
      if (s1 < s2) return -1;
      else if (s1 > s2) return 1;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Но она не проходит тест для массива "5 122 3 26 48". Получается "26 3 48 122 5", а должно "5 26 3 48 122". Не знаю, как пропустить нечетные числа: если писать "return 0" при встрече с нечетными, то программа случайно сортирует два числа, которые она в данный момент сравнивает. Что нужно исправить?

Comment: Что-то мне не кажется, что ваша задача решается, если использовать стандартный qsort. Это ж по идее нестабильная сортировка, она может перемещать даже те элементы, которые вы объявляете «равными».

Comment: @Gazon А вы уверены, что эта задача выполнима с использованием qsort?

Comment: @VladD, Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду под стандартный qsort. Ведь эта функция встроена в си.

Comment: создать второй массив, скинуть в него все четные числа, отсортировать "помощью страндартной функции языка", закинуть обратно?

Comment: @zRrr, Это корявый метод. Задача находится в разделе qsort.

Comment: @Gazon: Вот его, встроенный qsort, и имею в виду.

Comment: @Vlad, здесь приведена только функция сравнения. qsort требует пользовательскую функцию сравнения в качестве аргумента. Она-то и будет влиять на сортировку. Разве не так?

Comment: @Gazon: Именно так и есть. Но я не уверен, что при помощи одной лишь функции сравнения, вызывая встроенный qsort, вы сможете решить поставленную задачу.

Comment: Все еще интереснее, я повторил один к одному данный пример. собирал на linux, соотв. функция qsort из libc... По факту не произошло вообще ни одной перестановки. Причем порядок обхода элементов совершенно не тот, который должен быть для классической qsort. Нашел в интернете интересную заметочку, что современные библиотеки могут выбирать разные алгоритмы в зависимости от размеров массива

Comment: И еще заметил что в зависимости от ответов функции сравнения иногда кардинально меняется стратегия сортировки в итоге предсказать заранее будет ли qsort хотя бы еще раз сравнивать какой либо элемент у меня не выходит

Comment: @Mike: Оно и неудивительно. Проблема в том, что выбор pivot не предписан, поэтому последовательность сравнений угадать невозможно. А представить себе такой порядок, при котором нужные элементы остаются на местах, сложновато.

Comment: @Mike: надежда на то, что в компаратор приходят _указатели_, а значит, можно кроме значения элемента узнать и его _индекс_.

Comment: А еще я сейчас обнаружил, что в функцию передаются указатели на реальные элементы массива. Но сам массив в процессе сортировки остается неизменным (я его печатаю на каждой итерации) и только после завершения qsort он резко меняется. Я попробовал менять элементы сам, если считаю что qsort сделает это не правильно. Да, они между собой в массиве меняются, qsort их потом обратно меняет (они становятся в нужном мне порядке), но qsort при этом сдвигает их на другое место :)

Comment: @Mike: Резко меняется по завершению qsort? о_О Это какой-то странный неклассический qsort.

Comment: @VladD Т.е. судя по всему та версия qsort что у меня дает реальные указатели, а после ответа функции переносит их в свой внутренний массив на те позиции которые сочтет нужным. А перед завершением копирует свой массив в тот с которым вызывали

Comment: @Mike: То есть можно, конечно, отсортировать копию, как надо, на этапе препроцессинга, и затем на основе этого выдавать правильно больше/меньше, но это как-то слишком затратно.

Comment: @VladD Только надо еще алгоритм понять. он как то сразу идет по левому/правому подмасивам, причем по соседним элементам. Под конец вдруг сравнивает левый массив с серединой. При уже отсортированном массиве из 16 элементов он делает следующее:   1<>  2,   3<>  4,   1<>  3,   2<>  3,   5<>  6,   7<>  8,   5<>  7,   6<>  7,   1<>  5,   2<>  5,   3<>  5,   4<>  5,   9<> 10,  11<> 12,   9<> 11,  10<> 11,  13<> 14,  15<> 16,  13<> 15,  14<> 15,   9<> 13,  10<> 13,  11<> 13,  12<> 13,   1<>  9,   2<>  9,   3<>  9,   4<>  9,   5<>  9,   6<>  9,   7<>  9,   8<>  9

Comment: @Mike: По поводу порядка: если сравниваются чётные элементы, надо сравнивать их как обычно. Если сравниваются нечётные элементы, то сравниваем указатели, это оставит их порядок прежним. А вот как сравнивать чётный и нечётный элемент?

Comment: @VladD Да, проблема явно в этом, я уверен процентов на 95, что если бы под сравнение попадали всегда или чет или нечет то функция в вопросе дала бы правильный результат. Поэтому мне и хотелось для нестандартных ситуаций запомнить "неправильные" перестановки и попробовать их поменять обратно. Но особенности самого qsort сделать это так же не дали

Comment: @zRrr Вы всё правильно сказали. Всё остальное - разговоры.

Comment: @Mike Проще запомнить элементы, чем их перестановки. Тем более что места вставки отсортированных элементов известны.

Comment: Задачу только с помощью кастомной функции сравнения решить не получится. Когда вызывается `cmp(x, y)`, гдe `*x` четное, а `*y` нечетное, нужно знать положение `*x` в итоговом отсортированном массиве, чтобы вернуть правильный результат сравнения.

Comment: @VladD Перевод на c проблем не вызовет?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: Алгоритмические задачи часто получаются хорошими.

Comment: @Mike:Приведённый Вами протокол похож на сортировку бинарным слиянием, после 4-го элемента это чувствуется. Хотя внизу оптимально брать по 5 элементов (5!=120, и есть сбалансированное дерево на 7 сравнений).

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: По идее, не должен. Кроме совсем уж крайних случаев.

Comment: @VladD Я в том смысле, есть ли в С аналоги флипа

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно так, конечно:
1. Переписать чётные числа в отдельный массив.
2. Отсортировать полученный массив.
3. Последовательно заменить чётные числа исходного массива отсортированными числами из полученного массива.

<s>Теоретически можно перегнать чётные элементы в один конец массива, а нечётные в другой. Но чтобы вернуть их назад, понадобится протокол инверсий. А это не быстрая и не сортировка.</s>

P.S. Но можно и по полной программе:
Алгоритм такой:
1. Создаём flip-массив (в котором ключи и элементы поменялись ролями), применяя flip-функцию к исходному массиву.
2. Проводим сортировку с дополнительной опцией:
"если выполнены условия перестановки чётных элементов, то произвести обмен значениями для соответствующих элементов flip-массива".
3. Cортируем flip-массив, сохраняя связи между ключами и элементами.
4. Применяем flip-функцию к flip-массиву.

На PHP это выглядит так:

```
$common = array(5,122,3,26,48);
$flip = array_flip($common);
var_dump($common);
var_dump($flip);
$changes = array();
usort($common, function($a,$b) use(&$flip) { 
    if($a==$b) return 0;                        
    if(!(($a|$b)%2) && ($a>$b)){                // при перестановке чётных элементов
        $temp = $flip[$a];                      // обмениваем их ключи
        $flip[$a] = $flip[$b];
        $flip[$b] = $temp;
    }
    return $a-$b;
});
var_dump($common);
var_dump($flip);
asort($flip);
$common = array_flip($flip);
var_dump($common);
```

Результаты:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => int 5
  1 => int 122
  2 => int 3
  3 => int 26
  4 => int 48
array (size=5)
  5 => int 0
  122 => int 1
  3 => int 2
  26 => int 3
  48 => int 4
array (size=5)
  0 => int 3
  1 => int 5
  2 => int 26
  3 => int 48
  4 => int 122
array (size=5)
  5 => int 0
  122 => int 4
  3 => int 2
  26 => int 1
  48 => int 3
array (size=5)
  0 => int 5
  1 => int 26
  2 => int 3
  3 => int 48
  4 => int 122
```

Благодарности: [VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd), [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike).

Comment: Это решение ясно. И KoVadim в своем ответе как раз об этом пример привел.  Но лично я расцениваю условия задачи как "используя _только_ qsort и не производя других действий", иначе задача действительно очень простая. ТС как раз об этом вроде как намекал. хотя конечно, возможно, что тот кто изначально сформулировал задачу не думал что ее условия так жестко воспримут :) Собственно все разговоры под вопросом сводились именно к возможности "чистого" решения

Comment: @Mike Сортировка уменьшает энтропию (= логарифму числа допустимых состояний). И без дополнительной памяти никак. А у KoVadima неправильно, так что первым был zRrr

Comment: @Mike получилось

Answer (score -1):

Предположите, что p1 всегда левее в массиве чем p2 и давайте ответ в соответствии с этим

Comment: Уже предположили, только изменение ответа при той сортировке что реально происходит дает непредсказуемые последствия. Нашу переписку у вопроса почитай ...

Comment: Перечитал переписку - таки не вижу :-)

Comment: Во первых, если бы qsort делала то, что мы от нее ожидаем, то код в примере работал бы. потому как выдает правильные ответы в зависимости от предполагаемого положения элементов. Но как я указывал в переписке qsort руководствуется совершенно другими правилами и иногда перемещает элементы даже если ему ответили что этого делать не надо !

Comment: @Mike: qsort — нестабильная сортировка, имеет право изменять порядок равных элементов.

Comment: @VladD по факту она у меня умудрялась переставлять элементы даже не при 0, а при противоположном ответе. Т.е. я пробовал что бы заблокировать перемещение вместо +1 ответить -1. И это не всегда срабатывало