# Массивы с ключами в Visual Basic как в PHP

Tags: массивы, vb.net

Есть ли возможность создать описанное в заголовке? В PHP так всё хорошо с массивами, а в VS2017 как-то грустно, по крайней мере стандартными методами.

Comment: В пыхе плохо всё в массивами, там их нет. Вместо них какой-то комбайн, похожий на мап.

Comment: Все "красивые" реализации произвольного индекса используют [хэш-таблицы](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757363/java-hashmap-performance-optimization-alternative), так что не забывайте о цене вопроса

Comment: @D-side Удобства огромные, на самом деле. Но потом выясняется, сколько времени работает "оптимальный" алгоритм...

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov прекрасно, если это удобно, но надо понимать, что это не массив. Буквально вчера человек предложил (в другом языке) добавить в массив элемент по строковому индексу и сильно удивился, узнав, что этого сделать нельзя.

Comment: @D-side Я говорю о возможности "красивых" решений типа [такого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471119/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-qsort-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81/471158#471158). Но их трудно назвать быстрыми, если задуматься о фактической реализации.

Comment: @D-side Кстати, PHP-шники уже ищут пути для [отступления](https://habrahabr.ru/post/280262/). Осталось дождаться, когда это будет встроено.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov совершенно не против встраивания такой структуры данных в язык, она действительно на практике удобна для большинства случаев. Претензии только к тому, что её называют массивом, что путает людей. Вот. У меня всё :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В VB есть эквивалент, это Dictionary:

```
Dim dict = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
dict.Add("value1", "0001")
dict.Add("value2", "0010")
```

Или в одну строчку

```
Dim variable As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From { {"0001", "value1"}, {"0010", "value2"} }
```

Можете получать значения по ключам:

```
Dim val2 = dict("value2") ' <-- 0010
```