# Как увеличить производительность алгоритма, в котором по 1000 раз нужно определять, является ли число простым?

Tags: c, алгоритм, простые-числа

Решаю задачи проекта Эйлера. Одна из них записана следующим образом:

> Простые делители числа 13195 - это 5, 7, 13 и 29.
>   Каков самый большой делитель числа 600851475143, являющийся простым числом?

В принципе, ответ я получил: **6857** (правда не знаю, правилен ли он).
Проблема в том, что получал я его минут 20-30.

Время выполнения программы зависит от входных данных по какой-то весьма странной функции. Например, если я ищу самый большой простой делитель числа `5000003441`, то время выполнения программы ничтожно, меньше (намного меньше) секунды. Но стоит мне взять число `500000344` **(заметьте, число стало меньше на целый знак!)**, как время выполнения возрастает до нескольких секунд.

Я грешу на функцию определения простоты числа `isPrime()`. Я, конечно, попытался сделать ее максимально быстрой (убрал проверку четных чисел, чисел, оканчивающихся на 0, 2 или 5), но, видимо, этого не достаточно, когда речь идет о числах в несколько миллиардов.

Само собой, я пытался информацию в этих ваших интернетах искать, но в основном там приводятся алгоритмы **поиска** простых чисел, а не определения простоты числа. Самым быстрым для поиска являлось решето Эратосфена, но я не знаю, как его можно переформулировать для определения простоты.

Сам код (прошу особо не пинать, это одна из первых программ на C, речь сейчас не о рефакторинге, а конкретно об алгоритме).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int isPrime(unsigned long long int num) {
  if (num % 2 == 0 || num % 5 == 0 || num % 10 == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  unsigned long long int sqrtNum = sqrt(num);

  for (unsigned long long int i = 3; i <= sqrtNum; i += 2) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  return 1;
}

int main() {

  unsigned long long int num = 5000003441;
  unsigned long long int bgP = 0;

  for (unsigned long long int i = num; i > 1; i--) {
    if (num % i == 0 && isPrime(i)) {
      bgP = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  printf("%llu\n", bgP);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51360/discussion-on-question-by-smellyshovel----).

Comment: Чтобы не сомневаться, можно использовать сайт [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+600851475143)

Comment: Чисто по вашему алгоритму - начинать нужно не с самого числа, а с его квадратного корня (т.е. с ближайшего к нему нечетного числа) и уменьшать нужно не по 1, а по 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Не знаю, откуда у вас такие ужасы... Все, что помещается в 64 бита, можно решить за нормальное время простым перебором.

Просто нужно не искать самое большое простое число :), а **разложить число на простые множители и взять самый большой из них**.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

long long divd(long long N, long long start)
{
    for(long long i = start; i*i <= N; i+=2)
    {
        if (N%i == 0) return i;
    }
    return N;
}


int main()
{
    long long N = 600851475143ll;
    long long start = 3;

    while(N%2 == 0)
    {
        puts("2");
        N /= 2;
    }

    while(N > 1)
    {
        start = divd(N,start);
        N /= start;
        printf("%lld\n",start);
    }
}
```

[Этот код](http://ideone.com/co2nQE) разложил у меня ваше 600851475143 практически мгновенно (примерно 1.7ms), выведя

```
71
839
1471
6857
```

Для 500000344 - около 1.1ms, для 5000003441 - 0.4ms.

Comment: Пока что протестировать у себя не могу, обещаю завтра попробовать. Но пока что вопрос навскидку. Что за простые множители? Вы искали все простые числа, которые при перемножении друг на друга дадут искомое число? Это звучит куда более громоздко, чем начать уменьшать число на еденичку, каждый раз проверяя, является ли число простым (как сделал я), и как только такое число найдено - вывести его. Чисто если навскидку посмотреть, то совсем непонятно, почему ваш код работает быстрее. Завтра попытаюсь разобраться.

Comment: Именно. Я искал по сути простые множители. Если число простое - я делаю то же, что и вы (опуская проверку на простоту сомножителя). Если составное - то я, поскольку всегда иду снизу и по нечетным, обязательно наткнусь на простой множитель числа (грубо говоря, я не могу встретить делитель 15, потому что уже проверял деление на 3 и на 5). При этом я число делю на этот множитель и начинаю работу с уже меньшим числом с того же делителя.

Comment: В вашем варианте, увы, не избежать перебора практически всех чисел - ну, можно начать с N/2 для четного :) - например, представим, что ваше число - очень большое простое, умноженное, скажем, на 3. Результат - вы не можете начать перебор с квадратного корня, потому что пропустите это очень большое p. Вот вы и перебираете все триллионы чисел подряд. В то время как получив ту же тройку, простоту оставшегося числа вы проверите за квадратный корень...

Comment: Определенное ускорение можно получить, используя готовую таблицу простых чисел, но предвычисление может оказаться ненужным - как в вашем случае, где самое большое простое меньше 10000, и незачем строить всю таблицу. Так что для разового поиска достаточно и полного перебора, но для поиска в большом количестве предвычисление таблицы может оказаться и оправданным.

Comment: В общем так код вроде бы понятен. Мне не понятно только одно: почему вы делите N на start? Что этот старт из себя представляет вообще? Почему можно делить N только на него, а не на все числа подряд, как это делал я?

Comment: Смотрите, если мы нашли делитель, скажем, 23 - значит, до 23 все числа уже проверены. Поэтому нет смысла начинать опять проверку с 3 - можно начать с 23. Просто небольшая оптимизация, чтоб не делать лишних проверок. А делю я не на него, а на все нечетные, *начиная с него*. Потому сначала и идет многократное деление на 2 - чтоб точно знать, что больше четные делители нас не интересуют.

Comment: Ааааааа, вот теперь все становится на свои места. Спасибо, что объясняете мне. Я немного погонял еще свой вариант и убедился, что все-таки тормозит не столько определение на простоту, сколько именно постоянное деление, от которого вы избавились. Сейчас попробую сам реализовать. Спасибо еще раз :)

Comment: А, да, если вы насчет `N /= start;` - так здесь `start` - последний найденный делитель; теперь я ищу делители в меньшем числе - деленном на найденный делитель `start`.

Comment: Ну так главная оптимизация всегда - в оптимизации алгоритма, а не кода :)

Comment: Если наше число - произведение двух близких простых чисел, то быстрой факторизации не получится.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Естественно. Для `2147483587ull*2147483629ull` это почти 9 секунд.

Comment: Судя по всему, таблица простых чисел даёт хороший выигрыш. Особенно если простоту надо определять по 1000 раз

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Если мы работаем с `long long`, то простых чисел до 2^31 - более 105 миллионов, так что для их хранения нужно немало памяти; предвычисление же у меня занимает порядка 10-11 секунд. Выигрыш будет при таких вот числах - как приведенное 2 комментария назад, но для обычных, которые считаются за пару миллисекунд - их нужно считать минимум сотнями тысяч :)

Comment: Память - это несложный технический вопрос. Если проверять 1000 чисел одновременно, то можно обойтись одним предвычислением на каждый диапазон простых чисел. И следует иметь в виду, что примеры ОП не дают представления о реальной сложности вопроса, т.к. для их решения достаточно таблицы в 2К простых чисел.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov Как-то даже смешно предполагать, что кто-то будет делать предвычисление НЕ ДЛЯ ВСЕХ проверок :) А вот что выгоднее - тратить ли память и время на предвычисление - вопрос открытый. Было бы очень интересно посмотреть на ваш вариант реализации и экспериментальные проверки сравнения конкретных показателей времени с предвычислением таблицы простых чисел и без такового.

Comment: Время предвычисления - в моей программе ниже. Таблица простых чисел до 1 000 000 по ступенчатому алгоритму вычислена за 0.6 с.

Comment: А мне было бы интересно посмотреть, насколько можно улучшить показатели алгоритма в С, практически в аппаратной реализации. И отдельный вопрос - применение формата unsigned long.

Comment: До миллиона - это вообще мизер, там миллисекунд хватит. С выводом в файл - ну, до 100 мс. Требуется же 2^32, по-хорошему. Иначе такие большие числа, как у ТС, в общем случае не разложить. Словом, если хотите продолжать дискуссию - давайте продолжать ее с исходниками и хронометражом. Вы выдали гипотезу - значит, и бремя ее доказательства лежит на вас :) Без исходников - это все просто слова...

Comment: 27 секунд на миллион наибольших простых чисел <2^31. Исходники и расчёты - в ссылке к моему посту. А для разложения чисел до 10^12 таблицы простых чисел до миллиона достаточно.

Answer (score 3):

Для факторизации чисел до 10<sup>12</sup> целесообразно использовать таблицу простых чисел от 2 до 1 000 000, которую можно относительно быстро получить по ступенчатому алгоритму ["Решето Эратосфена"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/24957/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0/471155#471155).

PHP не работает с такими числами непосредственно, но даже с использованием неэффективной библиотеки длинных чисел это позволяет определить простоту числа не более чем за 0.27 с. Для составных чисел время работы алгоритма определяется величиной наибольшего множителя.

Текст программы на PHP:

```
<?php

$maxint = PHP_INT_MAX;
$maxval = 214700000;
$inter = 46340;         // =[sqrt($maxint)]

// вывод массива чисел строками по $width штук 
function print_p($arr, $width){
    print("<br>");
    $prn = $width;
    array_walk($arr, function($item, $key) use(&$prn, $width){
        if ($prn-- == 0){
            print ("<br>");
            $prn = $width-1;
        }
        print $item." ";
    });
    print("<br>");
}

function base_sieve(){
    global $inter, $p_base;
    $p0 = array(    2, 3, 5, 7, 11,             13, 17, 19, 23, 29,         31, 37, 41, 43, 47,         53, 59, 61, 67, 71,
                    73, 79, 83, 89, 97,         101, 103, 107, 109, 113,    127, 131, 137, 139, 149,    151, 157, 163, 167, 173,
                    179, 181, 191, 193, 197,    199, 211, 223);

    $p_sieve = range(0,$inter-1);
    array_walk($p0, function($item) use(&$p_sieve, $inter) {
        for($j=$item*$item; $j<$inter; $j+=$item) $p_sieve[$j] = 0; 
    });
    $p_sieve[1]=0;
    $p_base = array();
    array_walk($p_sieve, function ($item) use(&$p_base){
        if($item) $p_base[]=$item;
    });
}

function main_sieve($from, $to){
    global $maxint, $p_base;
    if(is_int($from) && is_int($to)) $p_sieve = range($from, $to);
    else exit(1);
    array_walk($p_base, function($item) use(&$p_sieve, $from, $to) {
        if($item*$item <= $to) {
            for($j=$to-$to%$item-$from; $j>=max($item*$item-$from,0); $j-=$item) {
                $p_sieve[$j] = 0;               
            }
        }
    });

    $p = array();
    array_walk($p_sieve, function ($item) use(&$p){
        if($item) $p[]="$item";
    });
    return $p;
}

function multipliers($long){
    global $p_main;
    printf("<br>%s = ",$long);
    foreach($p_main as $p){
        while(bcmod($long,$p) == "0"){
            print "$p";
            $long = bcdiv($long, $p);
            if($long == "1") return;
            print " * ";
        }
    }
    print($long);
}

$p_base=0;
$time_start = microtime(true); base_sieve(); $time_end = microtime(true);
print ("maxint=$maxint inter=$inter");
printf("<br> base_sieve: p_first = %d p_last = %d quantity = %d, time = %08.6f s", reset($p_base), end($p_base), count($p_base), $time_end-$time_start);
$time_start = microtime(true); $p_main = main_sieve(2,1000000); $time_end = microtime(true);
printf("<br>type of p_main is %s",gettype($p_main[0]));
printf("<br> main_sieve: p_first = %d p_last = %d quantity = %d, time = %08.6f s<br>", reset($p_main), end($p_main), count($p_main), $time_end-$time_start);
// print_p($p_main,25);
for($i=0; $i<100; $i++){
    $high = mt_rand(1,999); $low = mt_rand(0,999999999);
    $test_arr[$i] = "$high$low";
}
bcscale(0);
foreach($test_arr as $test){
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    multipliers($test);
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    printf(" time = %08.6f s", $time_end-$time_start);
}
?>
```

Результат:

```
maxint=2147483647 inter=46340
base_sieve: p_first = 2 p_last = 46337 quantity = 4792, time = 0.021571 s
type of p_main is string
main_sieve: p_first = 2 p_last = 999983 quantity = 78498, time = 0.567560 s

553691473520 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 5 * 6921143419 time = 0.237587 s
232687645263 = 3 * 3 * 31 * 601 * 937 * 1481 time = 0.000586 s
311288041383 = 3 * 11 * 3847 * 2452033 time = 0.191048 s
105764981153 = 13 * 3257 * 2497933 time = 0.191813 s
270836912430 = 2 * 3 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 429899861 time = 0.221387 s
361683186484 = 2 * 2 * 31 * 397 * 2207 * 3329 time = 0.001105 s
10706324001 = 3 * 2371 * 1505177 time = 0.190665 s
915824084166 = 2 * 3 * 3 * 23 * 23 * 96179803 time = 0.209428 s
385730194475 = 5 * 5 * 109507 * 140897 time = 0.038408 s
75439098918 = 2 * 3 * 3 * 17 * 246533003 time = 0.220314 s
551969280666 = 2 * 3 * 3 * 30664960037 time = 0.247161 s
565301524928 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 7 * 29 * 263 * 165443 time = 0.034738 s
820151988551 = 7 * 433 * 270587921 time = 0.222792 s
153451963245 = 3 * 5 * 7 * 16691 * 87559 time = 0.019925 s
558786413650 = 2 * 5 * 5 * 11175728273 time = 0.252510 s
551890312435 = 5 * 7 * 11 * 251 * 5711081 time = 0.193336 s
839421360031 = 29 * 126013 * 229703 time = 0.057032 s
318613379582 = 2 * 23 * 577 * 1637 * 7333 time = 0.002044 s
642262174328 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 37 * 113 * 19201811 time = 0.204186 s
371238997327 = 11 * 11 * 3068090887 time = 0.233256 s
708793150483 = 11 * 19 * 127 * 223 * 119747 time = 0.025917 s
327174441500 = 2 * 2 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 1259 * 519737 time = 0.100021 s
45074830741 = 71 * 18313 * 34667 time = 0.009357 s
915552254192 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 57222015887 time = 0.250288 s
855884231072 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 13 * 2057414017 time = 0.232373 s
813987872593 = 7 * 227 * 18691 * 27407 time = 0.007843 s
247656885108 = 2 * 2 * 3 * 97 * 2857 * 74471 time = 0.016392 s
961381476893 = 961381476893 time = 0.266906 s
269177206322 = 2 * 199 * 9539 * 70901 time = 0.015596 s
107655991002 = 2 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 7 * 284804209 time = 0.220538 s
899736483541 = 7 * 1019 * 126137177 time = 0.217558 s
457135478661 = 3 * 41 * 41 * 9281 * 9767 time = 0.003028 s
911680465430 = 2 * 5 * 7 * 60223 * 216263 time = 0.049649 s
459844355043 = 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 137 * 4604291 time = 0.192786 s
48477083806 = 2 * 43 * 107 * 313 * 16831 time = 0.004177 s
929615541285 = 3 * 5 * 59 * 8387 * 125243 time = 0.027615 s
20670498737 = 7 * 7 * 421846913 time = 0.220038 s
81355733000 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 5 * 5 * 5 * 81355733 time = 0.210158 s
354867234951 = 3 * 3019 * 39181543 time = 0.207279 s
608111108861 = 593 * 1025482477 time = 0.230331 s
934960353067 = 13 * 71 * 5107 * 198347 time = 0.041408 s
320943430213 = 7 * 71 * 645761429 time = 0.221753 s
725588681883 = 3 * 13 * 18604837997 time = 0.246502 s
159237072909 = 3 * 3 * 3 * 3 * 36479 * 53891 time = 0.014957 s
649175448030 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 331 * 65375171 time = 0.208241 s
228975729593 = 13 * 199 * 571 * 155009 time = 0.032429 s
565691149999 = 19 * 29773218421 time = 0.247251 s
280801496365 = 5 * 13 * 1693 * 2551697 time = 0.192637 s
130252052435 = 5 * 53 * 12703 * 38693 time = 0.009544 s
904961251319 = 111533 * 8113843 time = 0.202736 s
43185444263 = 13 * 1021 * 3253631 time = 0.192347 s
239919045791 = 239919045791 time = 0.262278 s
506552508393 = 3 * 113 * 34499 * 43313 time = 0.012443 s
34334216425 = 5 * 5 * 463 * 1297 * 2287 time = 0.000790 s
462834112368 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 37 * 191 * 1364423 time = 0.191600 s
673181425406 = 2 * 7 * 14983 * 3209263 time = 0.194858 s
623359229829 = 3 * 7 * 613 * 48423773 time = 0.207508 s
887791334640 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 137 * 409 * 9431 time = 0.002331 s
371468912017 = 7 * 461 * 4001 * 28771 time = 0.006963 s
196480685302 = 2 * 11 * 211 * 42326731 time = 0.207522 s
31944437007 = 3 * 7 * 8779 * 173273 time = 0.036914 s
726719056744 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 23 * 21647 * 182453 time = 0.039428 s
39952339943 = 509 * 78491827 time = 0.208226 s
109338494129 = 29 * 13591 * 277411 time = 0.056227 s
458442959553 = 3 * 3 * 50938106617 time = 0.252266 s
718274423190 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 19 * 359 * 617 * 5689 time = 0.001525 s
809920065021 = 3 * 493193 * 547399 time = 0.149381 s
242328062822 = 2 * 157 * 691 * 1116853 time = 0.190648 s
963136212357 = 3 * 11 * 134089 * 217661 time = 0.055360 s
837821068990 = 2 * 5 * 83782106899 time = 0.252241 s
51027834482 = 2 * 47 * 542849303 time = 0.220789 s
3158985259 = 9029 * 349871 time = 0.069631 s
33392531948 = 2 * 2 * 8348132987 time = 0.238608 s
68171229933 = 3 * 17 * 1336690783 time = 0.231692 s
839313478021 = 7523 * 111566327 time = 0.217574 s
925135648272 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 3 * 3 * 11 * 17 * 4217 * 8147 time = 0.002588 s
648126468152 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 81015808519 time = 0.250625 s
8564113326 = 2 * 3 * 491 * 1259 * 2309 time = 0.000803 s
725750348981 = 7 * 14747 * 7030489 time = 0.195158 s
931861413459 = 3 * 3 * 37 * 223 * 12548801 time = 0.205106 s
825593544897 = 3 * 11 * 25017986209 time = 0.246615 s
686362403522 = 2 * 16451 * 20860811 time = 0.206199 s
893975885122 = 2 * 397 * 1125914213 time = 0.231495 s
700595822165 = 5 * 251 * 12409 * 44987 time = 0.010773 s
275658217770 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 13 * 367 * 1925929 time = 0.192435 s
63594697433 = 2029 * 31342877 time = 0.208369 s
334145047658 = 2 * 37 * 1117 * 4042501 time = 0.192614 s
885803841664 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 7 * 137 * 601 * 12007 time = 0.003058 s
287771926051 = 37 * 7777619623 time = 0.235865 s
504655858977 = 3 * 19 * 181 * 467 * 104743 time = 0.022832 s
701802371020 = 2 * 2 * 5 * 7027 * 4993613 time = 0.194156 s
266606392998 = 2 * 3 * 11 * 4039490803 time = 0.233559 s
328160777839 = 17 * 29 * 89 * 503 * 14869 time = 0.003785 s
975677497762 = 2 * 11 * 17 * 179 * 14574097 time = 0.203605 s
12846269357 = 12846269357 time = 0.246531 s
504478606435 = 5 * 29 * 71 * 3779 * 12967 time = 0.003539 s
705626560463 = 11 * 64147869133 time = 0.250629 s
100212854528 = 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 53 * 1123 * 6577 time = 0.001749 s
824641883314 = 2 * 487 * 846654911 time = 0.223358 s
806932388679 = 3 * 268977462893 time = 0.263472 s
```

Comment: Жалко, что не C/C++... Сравнивать сложно.

Comment: Все до 2^31 - надо заменить `pow2(20)` на `pow2(31)`, снять комментарии с вывода самих чисел и получить файл примерно в гигабайт с небольшим :)

Comment: 2 ms на таблицу до миллиона - это намного лучше, чем у меня на PHP. Если вычислительные мощности различаются не на пару порядков.

Answer (score 2):

сперва сделаю некоторые замечания:

число 5000003441 - простое, поэтому для него одной проверки будет достаточно, следовательно его максимальным простым делителем будет само число 5000003441.

а для 500000344 придётся по перебирать так как оно составное.

касательно оптимизации:

например можете избавиться от дорогостоящего вычисления корня на каждой итерации, заменив

```
int isPrime(unsigned long long int num) {
  //...
  unsigned long long int sqrtNum = sqrt(num);    
  for (unsigned long long int i = 3; i <= sqrtNum; i += 2) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  }    
  //...
}
```

на

```
int isPrime(unsigned long long int num) {
  //...
  for (unsigned long long int i = 3; i*i <= num; i += 2) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
  //...
}
```

Comment: Стоп, подождите. Я специально вынес из цикла ф-ию `sqrt()`, чтобы при каждой итерации не считался корень. А вы внесли в цикл возведение в квадрат левой части (в то время как я избавился от выделения корня из правой). В чем суть? :D

Comment: @smellyshovel под избавлением я имел ввиду заменить sqrt на что нибудь попроще, а у вас на каждой итерации внешнего цикла где вызывается isPrime в котором есть вызов библиотечного sqrt который имеет разную реализацию на разных платформах.

Comment: Но выходит, что я вызываю sqrt() только внутри одного цикла (вложенность - 1), до которого даже не всегда доходит исполнение, кстати. А вы в своем коде предложили умножать i на i внутри цикла, который находится внутри цикла (вложенность - 2). По-моему это нехорошо.

Comment: @smellyshovel в обоих случая кол-во итераций внутреннго цикла будет одним и тем же, а почему sqrt может быть плох я объяснил

Answer (score 2):

Раз уж пошла такая пляска, то можно я тоже, только на Python? :)

```
import numpy as np, time

class primeIter:
    def __init__(self, cacheSize = 100000):
        self.cacheSize = cacheSize
        self.primes = []
        self.count = 0
        self.diap = 0
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self.count == len(self.primes):
            self.erast()
            return self.next()
        else:
            self.count+=1
            return self.primes[self.count-1]
    def erast(self):
        x = np.arange( self.diap+1, self.diap+self.cacheSize, 2)
        sqr = np.sqrt( self.diap+self.cacheSize )
        if self.count == 0:
            x[0]+=1
        for i in self.primes:
            x = x[ np.where( x % i != 0 ) ]
        while len(x)>0:
            if x[0]>sqr:
                self.primes+=list(x)
                break
            self.primes+=[x[0]]
            x = x[ np.where( x % self.primes[-1] !=0)]
        self.diap+=self.cacheSize

def test( n, cacheSize=100000 ):
    t1 = time.time()
    t = primeIter( cacheSize )
    m,k=1,1
    sqr = np.sqrt( n )
    while k<n:
        if k>sqr:
            m = int(n)
            break
        k = t.next()
        while n % k == 0:
            n = n/k
            m = k
    t2 = time.time()
    print (m,t2-t1)
```

Исполнение:

```
>>> test( 600851475143, 10000000 )
6857 6.416535139083862
>>> test( 600851475143, 1000000 )
6857 0.2682030200958252
>>> test( 600851475143, 100000 )
6857 0.01702594757080078
>>> test( 600851475143, 10000 )
6857 0.006017923355102539
>>> test( 600851475143, 1000 )
6857 0.018025875091552734
>>> test( 600851475143, 100 )
6857 0.1100931167602539
```

Другие тесты (лучшее время):

```
>>> test( 553691473520, 1000000 )
6921143419 0.5684139728546143
>>> test( 232687645263, 1000 )
1481 0.002012968063354492
test( 551969280666, 1000000 )
30664960037 0.5433969497680664
```

Первый аргумент - число, которое надо обработать, второй аргумент- размер "кэша" для решета Эрастофена, в данной задаче его можно вообще не делать, просто было любопытно самому.

Основное время работы при большом размере "кэша" - построение решета Эрастофена, зато потом получение простых чисел- просто обращение к элементу массива.

**Update:** Небольшая оптимизация в виде отсечения проверок, если превысили корень проверяемого числа дает ощутимый прирост в скорости создания решета.

Comment: А в каких единицах измерено время?

Comment: В секундах, много времени теряется на фильтрации массива. Решето- это фактически решето, как в школе на листочке учили вычеркивать, так и в этом алгоритме "в лоб" просто удаляются значения из массива.

Comment: Посмотрите ступенчатый алгоритм решета (ссылка к моему посту).

Comment: Не стал копировать Ваш алгоритм, просто добавил break, если превысился корень проверяемого числа и время значительно улучшилось.

Comment: Вы кстати используете единожды сгерерированные простые числа, у меня они создаются каждое обращение, так что, наверно мой алгоритм теперь обгоняет Ваш по скорости :)

Comment: 0.57s против 0.24 - это не лучше. При том, что у меня не проходит оптимизация с корнем (он слишком долго вычисляется в библиотеке длинных чисел).

Comment: :( ну вот, корень можно единожды вычислить вроде

Comment: Заодно буквы у Эратосфена переставьте :)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот этот вариант. Я давно не писал на Си - возможны ошибки.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int isPrime(unsigned long long int num) {
  if (num % 2 == 0 || num % 5 == 0 || num % 10 == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  unsigned long long int sqrtNum = sqrt(num);

  for (unsigned long long int i = 3; i <= sqrtNum; i += 2) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
  }

  return 1;
}

int main() {

  unsigned long long int num = 600851475143L;
  unsigned long long int bgP = 0;
  unsigned long long int sqrtNum = sqrt(num);

  sqrtNum = (sqrtNum % 2) ? sqrtNum : sqrtNum + 1 ;

  for (unsigned long long int i = sqrtNum; i > 1; i -= 2) {
    if (num % i == 0 && isPrime(i)) {
      bgP = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  printf("%llu\n", bgP);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Главная ошибка - что он может работать неверно. Например, возьмем число 15032381413, и получим в ответе 7, а не правильный ответ 2147483059...

Comment: согласен. я старался минимально изменить алгоритм автора и проверял только на его данных. подумаю, как можно его улучшить.

Answer (score 1):

Этo мой 3 код на Python:

```
def The_largest_simple_divider():
    yournumber = int(input("input you number:"))
    for i in range (1,yournumber):
        divider = yournumber / i
        intdivider = int(divider)
        floatdivider = float(divider)
        comparison = intdivider - floatdivider
        if comparison == 0:
            print('True',yournumber,"/",i,"=",divider)
        #else:
            #print('False',yournumber,"/",i,"=",divider)

The_largest_simple_divider()
```

Результат

```
True 600851475143 / 1 = 600851475143.0
True 600851475143 / 71 = 8462696833.0
True 600851475143 / 839 = 716151937.0
True 600851475143 / 1471 = 408464633.0
True 600851475143 / 6857 = 87625999.0
True 600851475143 / 59569 = 10086647.0
True 600851475143 / 104441 = 5753023.0
True 600851475143 / 486847 = 1234169.0
True 600851475143 / 1234169 = 486847.0
True 600851475143 / 5753023 = 104441.0
True 600851475143 / 10086647 = 59569.0
True 600851475143 / 87625999 = 6857.0
True 600851475143 / 408464633 = 1471.0
```

И если нужно найти самый большой простой делитель числа, то для начала нужно найти самый маленький (помимо 1) и поделить его на изначальное число `600851475143 / 71 = 8462696833.0`, то есть `600851475143 / 8462696833 = 71` GG WP EZI.

Comment: У вас есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1006950/edit), пользуйтесь ею для того, чтобы дополнть ответ. И что такое 3 код, не подскажите?

Comment: Но вопрос про C...

Comment: сам код тут имеет малое значение, тут дело в том что сам алгоритм действий можно было сделать намного проще обойдя стороной проблему долгого подбора чисел.

Answer (score 0):

```
a =600851475143
residue = 0
for i in range(1,a+1):
    if a % i == 0:
        print('Делитель равен',i)
        residue = a / i
        print('число после деления',residue)
        a = residue
        if a == 1:
            break
```

я вот так сделал

Answer (score 0):

Вот верный ответ на Python, проще не может быть, я даже зарегался, что бы написать, т.к. я ученик в IT, но профи в математике, пусть вам будет стыдно ))))

```
num = 600851475143
count = 2
while num != 1:
    if num % count == 0:
        num /= count
    else:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

поясняю: мы делим число на 2, пока без остатка, потом на 3 и т.д. до тех пор, пока не образуется единственное целое число, которое делиться лишь на себя и 1 (начинаем с 2, т.к. целое число делится на себя и 1)

Comment: 1. вопрос был про язык c, а не python. 2. это уж не говоря про «эффективность» деления на 4, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12 и т.д.

Comment: `/=` --> `//=`.

Comment: У меня ваш код работал для `5000003441` семнадцать минут. Это дольше чем необходимо.