# Как разложить число на множители

Tags: java, алгоритм, математика

Не получается разложить число `х` на множители:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
    if (x % i == 0) {
        a = i;
        System.out.print(a + " ")
    }
}
```

Comment: Этот код не раскладывает `x` на множители, а ищет все числа, на которые этот `x` делится нацело.

Answer (score 6):

1. Берём проверяемое число (`currentValue` - копию числа, дабы не портить оригинал) и первый множитель (`multiplier`) равный `2`.
2. Если проверяемое число кратно множителю, то выводим множитель на экран как подходящий, а проверяемое число делим на множитель.
3. Если множитель не подходит, то переходим к следующему множителю (`+1` в случае `2` и `+2` в других случаях).
4. Повторяем пункты 2 и 3 до тех пор, пока проверяемое значение больше `1`, а множитель меньше квадратного корня из оригинального числа (`sqrt`).
5. Если проверяемое значение не равно `1` после цикла, то выводим его.

   ```
   int x = 660;
   double sqrt = Math.sqrt(x);
   int currentValue = x;
   int multiplier = 2;
   while (currentValue > 1 && multiplier <= sqrt)
   {
       if (currentValue % multiplier == 0)
       {
           System.out.print(multiplier + " ");
           currentValue /= multiplier;
       }
       else if (multiplier == 2)
       {
           multiplier++;
       }
       else
       {
           multiplier += 2;
       }
   }
   if (currentValue != 1)
   {
       System.out.print(currentValue);
   }
   ```

Comment: Ну, как минимум, нет смысла пытаться делить на четные. И, кстати, если x - большое простое число - то вы так и будете проверять все значения `multiplier` от 2 до самого `x`? пока не доберетесь до исходного значения?

Comment: @Harry проход до `x`, а не до `sqrt(x)` - это да, ошибка в реализации алгоритма. Проход только по нечётным и `2` - это уже оптимизация. Исправил ответ, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Это издевательство - перебирать все подряд...
Посмотрите, например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/610885/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-1000-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F/611772?noredirect=1#comment841017_611772) - недавний вопрос.

Я в Java не мастак, поэтому расскажу словами (на C++ - см. по приведенной ссылке).
Если не строить таблицу простых чисел, то
1. Пока N четно, делим на 2 и записываем 2 как один из делителей (их может быть несколько).
2. Теперь N нечетно. Начиная с 3, проверяем все нечетные числа, до квадратного корня из N (проверяя для простоты i*i <= N, а не вычисляя корень), на делимость. Если не делится ни на одно - выписываем последний простой множитель - само N, и завершаем работу.
3. Если делится - выписываем очередной делитель, делим на него N, и повторяем цикл из п.2 для нового значения N, начиная не с 3, а с последнего найденного делителя.

Вот, собственно, и все.